# Programador de Tarefas Windows

Tags: php, windows

Tenho uma duvida em relação ao programador de tarefas Windows

Tenho tudo a correr normalmente.
Abre o Browser e executa o codigo php.

Mas depois existe a possibilidade de no fim fechar essa mesma pagina sozinho?

Comment: Que tal um `window.close();` em JS mesmo?

Comment: No final do php?

Comment: Depois do PHP, abrir `<html>` e colocar `<body onload="window.close();">`. Mas isso seria uma gambiarra, melhor fazer como o @perdeu respondeu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se precisa rodar um script php de forma automatica, chame ele pela linha de ao invés de invocar IE com o pagina/script desejado, assim você não se preocupa em fechar o navegador, quando o processamento acabar a janela do `cmd` será fechada.

Na sua bat o chame o php dessa forma:

```
php -f "C:\caminho_completo\script_automatico.php"
```

Para o comando ser reconhecido no terminal do DOS é necessário adicionar o caminho do executável do php à variável `PATH` do windows.

Isso pode ser feito atraves do atalho <kbd>win-key</kbd>+<kbd>break/pause</kbd> ou botão direito em (meu)computador > propriedades > configurações avançadas do sistema, guia avançado > variáveis de ambiente. Crie uma nova chamada `PHP_HOME` seu valor é a pasta onde está o .exe do php. Feito isso adicione o `PHP_HOME` ao `PATH` no final coloque: `;%PHP_HOME%;`.

Para testar abra um novo cmd e digite `php -v` caso tudo esteja certo ele deve exibir a versão do php.

Comment: mas ao abrir assim funciona nos ficheiro email.php? E consigo colocar isso a correr todos os dias as 12h?

Comment: @ChrisAdler funciona corretamente, crie um arquivo .bat, com o conteudo acima e agende ela. O seu script não precisa de nenhum interação/resposta do usuário certo?

Comment: Eu coloquei: php -f "C:\wamp\www\pasta\emailteste.php"
aparece a janela cmd e fecha e nao acontece mais nada.

Comment: @ChrisAdler, então aconteceu algum erro, na adicione uma linha com o seguinte comando `pause` assim da para ver o que foi escrito.

Comment: Obrigado. erro: 'php' não é reconhecido como comando interno...

Comment: @ChrisAdler sabe dizer se existe uma variável de ambiente como caminho do php(executavel)? ela deve ser adicionda ao `PATH` windows. Você pode ver isso, apertando a tecla `windows + break` > `configurações avandaçadas do sistema` aba `avançado`.

Comment: Encontrei nas variaveis do sistema o PATH e depois tenho de seguir o caminho que aparece lá e adicionar? ou faço editar ? Nunca mexi nesta parte

Comment: @ChrisAdler o ideal é criar duas delas o `PHP_BIN` o valor dela sera algo como `c:\xampp\php\php.exe` e o `PHP_HOME` com o valor: `c:\xampp\php`. Depois de criadas as duas você precisa alterar a variável `PATH` no fina coloque `;%PHP_HOME%;%PHP_BIN%;` Para verificar se funcionou abra um novo cmd e digite `php -v`.

Comment: Tentei de varias maneiras ontem e hoje e continua a não dar. Não utilizo o Xampp mas sim o Wamp mas deve dar na mesma correcto?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18799/discussion-between-perdeu-and-chrisadler).

Comment: @ChrisAdler, como você deixou o `PHP_HOME` e coloque o final do `PATH`

Comment: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe . path: C:\Program (...);%PHP_HOME%;%PHP_BIN%;

Comment: @ChrisAdler é para ser isso mesmo. o PHP_HOME e PHP_BIN foram criadas em variáveis do sistema ou variáveis do usuário?

Comment: ambas em variáveis do sistema

Comment: já consegui por a funcionar. Muito obrigado

Comment: @ChrisAdler, o que estava errado? que bom que resolveu.

Comment: Coloquei apenas no path C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer um evento chamando um batch, nesse batch você controla o comportamento:

```
taskkill /f /im chrome.exe >nul 2>nul

start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" http://localhost/

taskkill /f /im chrome.exe >nul 2>nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando quiser fechar a janela você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
echo "<script>window.close();</script>";
```

Mas dependendo de sua aplicação, a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40922/3010) do @perdeu seria melhor chamando o PHP na sua bat dessa forma:

```
php -f "C:\caminho_completo\script_automatico.php"
```

Pra fazer as chamadas ao sistema o PHP possui a função `system()`, leia a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.system.php) :

```
string system (string $command [,int &$return_var])
```

Comment: Será apenas para enviar email.Mas como fiz tinha de fechar manualmente a pagina