# Chamando função PHP por arquivo BAT

Tags: php, windows, batch

Preciso criar um arquivo BAT que deverá ser executado todo dia 25. Ele deverá executar uma função chamada emailAniversariantes(), que foi definida para a programação de um site dentro de dois arquivos (controller e model).

Como eu assumi esse site de outro desenvolvedor e o mesmo utilizava de um aplicativo pra executar essa função todo dia 25, precisaria que o arquivo BAT fizesse o mesmo. Acredito que a utilização de comandos PHP para o prompt de Windows possam ser a solução. Mas ainda não achei na internet os comandos corretos pra executar direto essa função do controller.

Minha função dentro do arquivo do diretório Model:

```
public function emailAniversariantes(){
$data = getdate();
$mes = $data[mon];
$ano = $data[year];
if($mes==12){
    $mes = 1;
    $ano = $ano+1;
}else{
    $mes = $mes+1;
    if($mes<10){
        $mes = '0'.$mes;
    }
}

$sqlUnidades = "select id, nome from unidade where ind_unidade_ativa=1 order by nome";
$resUnidades = System::element('db')->query($sqlUnidades);

$corpo = "";
$corpo .= "<div style='float:left;width:100%; height:3px; background-color:gray; margin-bottom:20px;'></div>";

$corpo .="<div style='font-family:Lucida Sans; font-size:13px;' color='black'>
            <br>Bom dia.<br>Segue abaixo a relação dos aniversariantes do próximo mês.<br>
            Se possível, sugerimos que entrem em contato com eles para desejar feliz aniversário!<br><br><br>
            </div>";

foreach ($resUnidades as $rUnidades){
    $sql = "Select u.id as id_usuario, i.id as id_investidor, uu.id_unidade, un.nome nome_unidade, u.email, 
            DATE_FORMAT(i.data_nasc, '%d/%m/%Y') as data_nasc, i.razao_social as nome, i.telefone, i.nome_responsavel,
            (Select count(*) from usuario u join usuario_unidade uu on (uu.id_usuario = u.id) join investidor i on (i.id_usuario = u.id)
            where uu.id_unidade = ".$rUnidades['id']." and month(i.data_nasc)=".$mes.") AS count
            from usuario u join usuario_unidade uu on (uu.id_usuario = u.id) 
            join unidade un on (un.id = uu.id_unidade)
            join investidor i on (i.id_usuario = u.id)
            where uu.id_unidade = ".$rUnidades['id']." and month(i.data_nasc)=".$mes."
            ORDER BY i.razao_social";
    $res = System::element('db')->query($sql);

    if($res[0]['count']>=1){
        $corpo .="<div style='width:100%; height:100%; float: left; margin: 25px 0;'>";

        $corpo .="<b>Unidade: ".$rUnidades['nome']."</b>";

        $corpo .="<table style='width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; display: table; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px;'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr stile='border-collapse: collapse; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px;'>
                            <th style='border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #F7F7F7; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;'>Nome</th>
                            <th style='border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #F7F7F7; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;'>Telefone</th>
                            <th style='border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #F7F7F7; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;'>E-mail</th>
                            <th style='border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #F7F7F7; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;'>Responsável</th>
                            <th style='border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #F7F7F7; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;'>Data de Nascimento</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>";
        $corpo .="<tbody>";

        foreach ($res as $r){

            $corpo .= "<tr stile='border-collapse: collapse; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px;'>";
                $corpo .= "<td style='border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;'>".$r['nome']."</td>";
                $corpo .= "<td style='border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;'>".$r['telefone']."</td>";
                $corpo .= "<td style='border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;'>".$r['email']."</td>";
                $corpo .= "<td style='border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;'>".$r['nome_responsavel']."</td>";
                $corpo .= "<td style='border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 3px solid #E2E1E0; padding: 5px; text-align: center;'>".$r['data_nasc']."</td>";
            $corpo .= "</tr>";
        }
        $corpo .="</tbody>";
        $corpo .="</table></div>";
    }
}

$corpo .= "<div style='width:100%; height:56px; float:left;'>";
$corpo .= "<table><font face='Lucida Sans'>";
$corpo .= "<tr>";
$corpo .= "<td style='float:left;'><div style='font-size:10px; float:left; width:200px; margin-top:5px; position:relative; margin-right:15px; float:left;'>Tel: +55 11 3577-7173<br>";
$corpo .= "email@meusite.com.br<br>";
$corpo .= "http://www.meusite.com.br/</td>";

$corpo .= "<td><img style='float:left; position:relative'></td>";

$corpo .= "</table></font></div></div>";
$corpo .= "</div>";

$arrayEmails = array();
$arrayEmails[0]="email2@meusite.com.br";
$arrayEmails[1]="email3@meusite.com.br";
$arrayEmails[2]="email4@meusite.com.br";
Util::enviaEmail("Remetente", $arrayEmails, "Aniversariantes ".$mes."/".$ano, $corpo,implode(";",$arrayEmails));
return "1";
}
```

Como a função é chamada pelo arquivo Controller:

```
public function emailAniversariantes() {
$retorno = CadAdmin::emailAniversariantes();
echo $retorno;
}
```

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Veja se [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40922/91) ajuda

Comment: Copiei exatamente o script da função em PHP e mandei executá-lo pelo windows prompt. Mas não deu certo. Será que é por ter no código funções como System::element('db')->query($sql); e Util::enviaEmail("Remetente", $arrayEmails, "Aniversariantes ".$mes."/".$ano, $corpo,implode(";",$arrayEmails)); que utilizam funções de outros arquivos do site?

Answer (score 4):

Você vai ter que criar um arquivo PHP, pode inclusive ser o mesmo que você definiu a função, porém ele terá mais ou menos a estrutura a seguir

```
<?php
suachamadadefuncao();

function suafuncao() {}

?>
```

Depois você pode criar um .bat com a estrutura assim:

```
@echo off

caminhoparaseuphp.exe caminhoparaoarquivophp.php
```

Vamos supor que seu PHP.exe fique no diretório C: assim como este arquivo php que você criou, o comando seria

```
@echo off
C:/php.exe C:/seuphp.php
```

Dessa maneira você estará executando o arquivo PHP dentro do prompt de comando, que por sua vez chamaria sua função. Agora é só usar o próprio scheduler do windows (taskschd.msc) para agendar para o dia 25.

Comment: Copiei exatamente o script da função em PHP e mandei executá-lo pelo windows prompt. Mas não deu certo. Será que é por ter no código funções como System::element('db')->query($sql); e Util::enviaEmail("Remetente", $arrayEmails, "Aniversariantes ".$mes."/".$ano, $corpo,implode(";",$arrayEmails)); que utilizam funções de outros arquivos do site?

Comment: Não isso não deveria interferir desde que os caminhos estejam corretos. Você estaria executando o php.exe com um parâmetro do arquivo que ele via executar