# Agendar tarefa via windows num arquivo php

Tags: php, windows

***Código:***

```
foreach (glob('ImgCode/*.png') as $Files) {
  unlink($Files);
}
```

***Problema:*** Preciso rodar este código para apagar as fotos da pasta, todo dia as 00:00 horas.

Gostaria de saber que possibilidades existem, qual seria a melhor, e como começar para fazer.

Comment: Sim é possível! veja se isso responde => [Programador de Tarefas Windows](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40922/91)

Comment: Outra pergunta que também pode lhe atender => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/152429/31016